# how to solve facebook get access token error in python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have installed facebook module in python through console

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

then registered to facebook api to get app_id and app_secret.I am not disclosing them below.

```
import facebook
app_id = '00000'
app_secret = 'xxxx'
access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(app_id,app_secret)
```

when i execute it to get access_token, my python console throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-0dfc0fd92367>", line 1, in <module>
access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(app_id,app_secret)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_app_access_token'
```

please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known Problem. Just uninstall `facebook` and `facebook-sdk` and then reinstall only `facebook-sdk`.

```
sudo pip uninstall facebook
sudo pip uninstall facebook-sdk
sudo pip install facebook-sdk
```

Furthermore you can implement your own `get_app_access_token` by:

```
def get_app_access_token(app_id, app_secret):
    """Get the access_token for the app.

    This token can be used for insights and creating test users.

    @arg app_id :type string :desc retrieved from the developer page
    @arg app_secret :type string :desc retrieved from the developer page

    Returns the application access_token.

    """
    # Get an app access token
    args = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': app_id,
            'client_secret': app_secret}

    f = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
                              urllib.urlencode(args))

    try:
        result = f.read().split("=")[1]
    finally:
        f.close()

    return result
```

Result will have your **access token**.

Comment: Thank you so muc for the help @naqushab.. well after successfully execulting it, i got an error in my next line of code

Comment: graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'